# Error while generating an ipa build in ios for flutter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I have an error while generating an ipa in flutter for IOS. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
   1 warning generated.
    6 warnings generated.
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
    CompileC
    /Users/sky289/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cpzvoijtssjcgrdefbhtmqwuabgs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/Interme
    diateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/TOCropViewController.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TOCropViewController.o
    /Users/sky289/AndroidStudioProjects/lesvoisinsv3_flutter/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.m normal
    arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    DIBlockByRefStruct on DICompositeType is no longer supported
    !332 = !DICompositeType(tag: DW_TAG_structure_type, scope: !3, file: !3, size: 384, flags: DIFlagReservedBit4, elements: !333)
    DIBlockByRefStruct on DICompositeType is no longer supported
    !343 = !DICompositeType(tag: DW_TAG_structure_type, scope: !3, file: !3, size: 384, flags: DIFlagReservedBit4, elements: !344)
    DIBlockByRefStruct on DICompositeType is no longer supported
```